# DwmSetWindowAttribute does not work with DWMWA_CLOAK

Tags: c#, windows-10, pinvoke, dwm

I recently started using lower level windows APIsn with C# for an application prototype and I stumble upon a problem that I cannot get my way around: Consider the following piece of code:

```
public class dW
{
    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
    public static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, DwmWindowAttribute dwAttribute, ref int pvAttribute, int cbAttribute);

    [Flags]
    public enum DwmWindowAttribute : uint
    {
        DWMWA_NCRENDERING_ENABLED = 1,
        DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY,
        DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED,
        DWMWA_ALLOW_NCPAINT,
        DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS,
        DWMWA_NONCLIENT_RTL_LAYOUT,
        DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION,
        DWMWA_FLIP3D_POLICY,
        DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS,
        DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP,
        DWMWA_DISALLOW_PEEK,
        DWMWA_EXCLUDED_FROM_PEEK,
        DWMWA_CLOAK,
        DWMWA_CLOAKED,
        DWMWA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION,
        DWMWA_LAST
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }

    public void HideWindow()
    {
        int value = 0x01;
        int hr  = DwmSetWindowAttribute(Handle, DwmWindowAttribute.DWMWA_CLOAK, ref value, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int)));
    }
}
```

Consider that Handle is a well defined `IntPtr`. I'm trying to Cloak a window using `DwmSetWindowAttribute` but for some strange reason it never works (the window remains visible all the time), and the result (stored in `hr`) is always -2147024891. I simply do not understand why this happens, since the code seems the be correct (imho). 
Do you have any clues?

Thanks

Comment: -2147024891 = Access Denied. is the handle from an elevated application?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply! Actually not, I get this result for any window I try to cloak.

Comment: [SharpDX](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.DirectComposition/DesktopDevice.cs#L62) only uses **size(int)** as last parameter

Comment: Did not work :(. I see that using other flags will cause effects, but cloaking doesn't. If I want to completely hide a window from the user (from the desktop, take, alt-tab, etc), is cloaking enough?

Comment: I never used DWMWA_CLOAK so I have no idea what is wrong in your case.

Comment: Kom op jongens, dat is echt geen oplossing haha... Anyways, is there any guidelines to use that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same result (access denied) too, even with Admin, and I figured out only system shell and application itself can set cloak, third-party process will be denied.